# Javascript scroll bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I've built a small chat div where people can chat.
It works with AJAX which pulls to records and places them.

Everything is working fine except for a minor problem.
Every time AJAX is called I want it to scroll the div down to the bottom. (Latest chat messages are on the bottom)

However, I can't figure out how to track if a user is already scrolling inside the chat div themselves or not.

I want to prevent the "auto scroll down" in case a user is active inside the chat.

How would I go around doing this?

HTML of the chat:

```
<div id="chat">
  <div id="chatoutput></div>
</div>
```

Javascript that makes it scroll to the bottom:

```
jQuery("#chat").scrollTop($("#chat")[0].scrollHeight);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can disable the auto scroll down if the user once scrolled manually:

```
$("#chat").scroll(function() {
    autoScrollEnabled = false;
});
```

You have to check autoScrollEnabled before scrolling down though.

```
if (autoScrollEnabled) {
  jQuery("#chat").scrollTop($("#chat")[0].scrollHeight);
}
```

You could also store a DateTime value to check when the user last scrolled and enable autoScroll if that was, say, 1 minute ago.

Comment: Love it, thank you very much :)

How would you go around with the DateTime? Store it locally or database?

Comment: I would store it locally. In database it would only be relevant on a reload. But then you want to scroll at the bottom anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Just use simple `javascript` method.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     var objDiv = document.getElementById("chat");
     objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
});
```